# HTML CSS Cannot click on links

Tags: html, css, wordpress

There are quite a lot of questions asking almost the same questions. Now I have met the same issue and I find out that rarely there are answers that explains how to find out the root cause. It seems that the reason is some other `div` overlays on top of the links, but how could I find out which `div` is the one to blame. I have set the link's z-index to large numbers but it doesn't work. I don't know why. Could anyone help me on how to debug this issue?

My tougher situation is that the website is a Wordpress one. There are a lot of nested `div`s. Can I use the browser's inspect tool to quickly find out how to fix such issues?

[link](https://acdebernadac.fr/corporate-programs/3-hours-programs/high-social-dining-etiquette-class/) - on this website, the left sidebar's links are not clickable.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is with this class `#theme-page:before` it has `position: absolute;` and it's covering all of the page elements, when you removing it everything will work properly.

Comment: You can use Chrome to inspect element and debug, btw it's the most important debugging tool.

Comment: this link will help you understand what I mean [Google DevTool](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)

Comment: i'm using the inspect mode. i could try to toggle/edit each of the attribute and style in the html/css in this mode. but for me i lack the knowledge of why this :before and position: absolute will cause this issue and if i want to achieve the same layout (background picture) how could i do it?

Answer (score 0):

you may try this : **include** it at the very bottom of your `css` style:

```
#theme-page:before {
    content: " ";
    position: relative; /*update*/
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0.1;
}
```

Please comment below if you have problem with this :)

Comment: greetings dear, I want to tell you that `position: block` is invalid property value! but when you put invalid value, by default the browser will put the initial value which means in this case it will be `position: relative;`

Comment: @stcheng because it covers all your elements by the position property.

Comment: @AlaaMh Indeed, sorry for that :) it is `relative` as the `default`

Comment: @stcheng You may try the code now, and if there's a problem with it, then let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty obvious that you have problem with `position: absolute;` when you inspect element. Look at the image and remove it , and it should be work 
[Click to see screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MqNC.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the stack order of `#theme-page::before` You can simply fix this with `z-index` property

```
#theme-page::before {
  bottom: 0;
  content: " ";
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.1;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1; /* newly added */
}

#theme-page {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1; /* newly added */
}
```